# Vector layer from MapServer WFS not displaying in OpenLayers 6

Tags: postgis, openlayers, geojson, wfs, mapserver

I want to display a WFS layer in GeoJSON format on my map via OpenLayers. All my layers in WMS appear, only the one in WFS does not appear.
I did create a "WEB" block in the mapfile. And my layers are saved in a pgAdmin database (Postgres) with PostGIS.

```
MAP
    NAME carte_rando
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    EXTENT 428111 6164472 719547 6367853
    SIZE 1000 800
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    SHAPEPATH ./shapes

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3857"
    END

    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "geojson"
        DRIVER "OGR/GEOJSON"
        MIMETYPE "application/json;subtype=geojson"
        FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=stream"
        FORMATOPTION "FORM=SIMPLE"
    END

    WEB
        TEMPLATE "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/site_web_rando.html"
        IMAGEPATH "./images/"
        IMAGEURL "/images/"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "WMS_PDIPR_cd31" 
            "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mapfile_rando.map&"
            "wms_srs"   "EPSG:3857"
            "wms_abstract" "Couches images WMS limites, routes, eau et sentier"
            "wms_enable_request" "*"
            "WMS_FEATURE_INFO_MIME_TYPE" "text/html"
            "wfs_title" "WFS_PDIPR_cd31"
            "wfs_version" "1.1.0"
            "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mapfile_rando.map&"
            "wfs_srs" "EPSG:3857"
            "wfs_abstract" "Couche signaletique en WFS"
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"
        END
    END

    TEMPLATEPATTERN "*"

    LAYER
        NAME signaletique
        TYPE point
        STATUS on
        EXTENT 428111 6164472 719547 6367853
        DATA signaletique


        METADATA
            "wfs_title" "signaletique"
            "wfs_srs" "EPSG:3857"
            "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mapfile_rando.map&"
            "gml_featureid"     "id"
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"
            "wfs_getfeature_formatlist" "GeoJSON"
        END

        CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
        CONNECTION "host=localhost port=5432 dbname='PDIPR_cd31' user='xxxxx' password='xxxxxx'"
        DATA "geom FROM signaletique USING UNIQUE id"

        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:2154"
        END 

        CLASS 
            NAME signaletique
            TEMPLATE site_web_rando.html
                STYLE
                    SYMBOL "square"
                    size 8
                    COLOR 70 130 180
                    OUTLINECOLOR 65 105 255
                END
            END
    END

END
```

With the following URL I have the GeoJSON data which is displayed and formatted correctly. I deduce that my WFS layer works.

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapfile_rando.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=signaletique&outputformat=geojson

So I called my layer with the OpenLayers library:

```
<!-- Couche signaletique_sentier -->
            var signaletiqueSource = new ol.source.Vector({ //source signaletique WFS
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                loader: function(extent) {
                    return 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapfile_rando.map&SERVICE=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=signaletique&' +
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
                    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
                },
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
            });

            var couchesignaletique = new ol.layer.Vector({ //Couche signaletique
                visible: true,
                source:signaletiqueSource,
                ratio:1,
            });

            var view = new ol.View({
                center: [130905, 5367021],
                projection:'EPSG:3857',
                zoom: 9.2,
            });


            var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [raster, departements, communes, reseau_hydrographique, autoroutes,
                nationales, departementales, autres, traces_sentier, couchesignaletique, vector],
                target: 'map',
                view: view,
            });
```

But my layer does not appear. Yet I followed the instructions given in other forum responses similar to my problem.
And I followed the instructions given with an example of OpenLayers:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=wfs

At the beginning of my work, I displayed my layer in WMS Image and it worked perfectly. But I want to be able to extract the attribute data from my layer and be able to modify and then save them.
When on my web page I do "Examine the element" no error appears.

I have the impression that there is no error, but there must be one.

Comment: Please also be careful to follow the proper MS4W settings for IMAGEURL and IMAGEPATH (I designed MS4W so that it comes out-of-the-box ready with those already configured).  Likely you will face this grief later down the road without those properly set: see my recent answer here for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361400/mapserver-html-template-doesnt-display-map-image

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution if it can help someone.

```
var signaletiqueSource = new ol.source.Vector({ //source signaletique WFS
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url:'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapfile_rando.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=signaletique&outputformat=geojson',
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            });

            var couchesignaletique = new ol.layer.Vector({ //Couche signaletique
                visible: true,
                source:signaletiqueSource,
                ratio:1,
            });
```

I don't know why it didn't work with the other solution. I think it was missing the "url" tag.

I hope this would help some beginners like me!

Answer (score 1):

In your original code you should change `loader:` to `url:` as the function doesn't load features, it simply returns a url with bbox parameter

```
        var signaletiqueSource = new ol.source.Vector({ //source signaletique WFS
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function(extent) {
                return 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapfile_rando.map&SERVICE=WFS&' +
                'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=signaletique&' +
                'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
                'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
        });
```

If you don't specify bbox in the url it is equivalent to using strategy `all` for every extent OpenLayers loads so you would need to change the strategy to `ol.loadingstrategy.all` to avoid unnecessary loads.